# Display angular html as it is calculated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The table I'm displaying takes quite a while to show up (25 seconds). While all the html is being generated, the area where the table would be is blank. I'm wondering if there is a way to show each row in the table as it calculates the values for the rows, rather than waiting until the end to show it.

I'd resort to pagination, but there are some 'running total' type columns, which would make tracking state between pages rather complicated. The ajax data loads in 2-3 seconds, and the data all displayed by itself, without any table markup, takes another 2-3, so it seems that the table html is what is taking all the time.

Here is some example code (I don't have access to it at the moment, but it gives an idea of the kinds of calculations I'm doing and how I'm displaying it)

html

```
<table> 
    <tr ng-repeat="commission in commissions">
        <td>{{commission.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{addToRunningTotal(commission.amount)}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
$scope.addToRunningTotal = function(amount) {
    runningTotal += amount;
    return runningTotal;
};
```

Comment: loop over the data you are showing and add a new row for each entry.

Comment: how? using something other than ng-repeat?

Comment: When you generate your table, make sure that the values that are displayed in the table are not triggering some calculation (this would happen for every value for every digest), which would make it extremely slow and painful.

Comment: That's a dangerously long time. Sounds like it could cause some cross browser crash issues. Would sure look to optimize it. Pagination would be a good place to start

Comment: Without any code to show exactly how you are loading the data and rendering the table it's hard to say if it's taking this long *because* of how Angular implements the ng-repeat directive, or in spite of it. Might be worthwhile to profile your page in the Chrome inspector.

Comment: please update question with code..